# How to resolve my problem with installing r-base?

Tags: 16.04, r

I'm facing a problem while installing r-base in Ubuntu 16.04. It's showing some error of unable to meet dependencies.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
r-base : 
Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.2-2zesty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.2-2zesty) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
W: Target Sources (Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:73 and /etc/apt/sources.list:77
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install R from the Ubuntu 16.10 repository while you are using 16.04. Use the correct repository. Fix the duplicate entry in the sources.list file.

Comment: @user68186 Isn't zesty not 17.04? But beside that you're right.

Comment: @Videonauth you are right! It is 16.04 versus 17.04!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt list --upgradable
```

Then

```
sudo apt install r-base
```